# Can't use void Function in onPressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I made void function and tried to use in Scaffold but it's keeping has Undefined error. I don't get reason about that. give me advice please.

```
    import 'package:auth_practice/secondpage.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FingerprintApp(),
    ));
    
    class FingerprintApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const FingerprintApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
     
      @override
      State<FingerprintApp> createState() => _FingerprintAppState();
    }
    
    
    class _FingerprintAppState extends State<FingerprintApp> {
      LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();
      late bool _canCheckBiometric;
      late List<BiometricType> _availableBiometrics; // this list will store all types
      //of biometric sensor like face, finger...
      String autherized = "Not autherized"; // this String will check if we can
    //access our app or not
    
    
      // Now, create the function that will allow uus to check our biometric sensors
      Future<void> _checkBiometric() async{
        bool canCheckBiometric;
        try{
          canCheckBiometric = await auth.canCheckBiometrics;
        } on PlatformException catch(e) {
          print(e);
        }
        if(!mounted) return;
        setState(() {
          _canCheckBiometric = _canCheckBiometric;
        });
      }
    
      //now that we checked if we are allowed to check our biometric lets get
      // the availanle biometrics sensor on our device
      Future<void > _getAvailableBiometrics() async{
    
        List<BiometricType> availableBiometric;
    
        try{
    
          availableBiometric = await auth.getAvailableBiometrics();
        } on PlatformException catch(e) {
          print(e);
        }
        if(!mounted) return;
        setState(() {
          _availableBiometrics = availableBiometric;
        });
      }
    
      Future<void> _authenticate() async {
        bool authenticated = false;
    
        try{
          authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
              localizedReason: "Scan your finger to authentie",
              useErrorDialogs: true,
              stickAuth: false
          );
        }on PlatformException catch(e) {
          print(e);
        }
    
        if(!mounted) return;
    
        setState(() {
          //here we can add what our app will do if the user authenticated first
          autherized = authenticated ? "Autherized success" : "Failed to authenticate";
          if(authenticated) {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
          }
          print(autherized);
          // note that you must configure your device  and add a finger print
        });
      }
      //before we test our app we should first initate the state and call
      // our tow first function
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        //TOdo: implement initstate
        _checkBiometric();
        _getAvailableBiometrics();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xfFF3C3E52),
              body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: Text("Login,", style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 48.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),),
                    ),
                    Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/fingerprint.webp',
                            width: 120.0,
                          ),
                          Text("FingerPrint auth", style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),),
                          Container(
                            width: 150.0,
                            child: Text("Authenticate using your fingerprint instead of your password",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                height: 1.5
                              ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: _authenticate,
                                elevation: 0.0,
                                color: Color(0xFfF04A5ED),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                                  child: Text("Autentic", style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            )
        );
      }
    }
```

In Related Question,

1. Future _authenticate()
2. The ElevatedButton in Widget build(BuildContext context)

Arn't they in same level? I don't get why Button's property doesn't read the function 'authenticate',,

Comment: Are you using `_authenticate` in the same file as where you defined that function?

Comment: Please share your complete code so that we can identify the problem. Looks like your function and Scaffold widget are not under the same scope and your function is private so kindly check these points and review your code. Otherwise share your code.

Comment: Could you check again one more time please? I amend that and get full code now. Thanks. @jamesdlin

Comment: Could you check again one more time please? I amend that and get full code now. Thanks. @FaizanDarwesh

Comment: @Uranus_ly Is this actually your full code?  You seem to have two `build` methods in the same class.  Can you answer my earlier question?

Comment: Yes They' are all in same class. Is it cause problem if they have two build methods? @jamesdlin

Comment: @Uranus_ly A Dart class can't have two methods with the same name...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using separate file, 1st remove `_` from `_authenticate` to make it public like `authenticate()` and import the file on working file and use as

```dart
 onPressed: authenticate,
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your code with this modified version.
The problem in your code is you have two build methods and the one in which you want to pass_authenticate method as onPressed is outside the scope.

```
import 'package:auth_practice/secondpage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: FingerprintApp(),
));

class FingerprintApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const FingerprintApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FingerprintApp> createState() => _FingerprintAppState();
}


class _FingerprintAppState extends State<FingerprintApp> {
  LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();
  late bool _canCheckBiometric;
  late List<BiometricType> _availableBiometrics; // this list will store all types
  //of biometric sensor like face, finger...
  String autherized = "Not autherized"; // this String will check if we can
  //access our app or not


  // Now, create the function that will allow uus to check our biometric sensors
  Future<void> _checkBiometric() async{
    bool canCheckBiometric;
    try{
      canCheckBiometric = await auth.canCheckBiometrics;
    } on PlatformException catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }
    if(!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _canCheckBiometric = _canCheckBiometric;
    });
  }

  //now that we checked if we are allowed to check our biometric lets get
  // the availanle biometrics sensor on our device
  Future<void > _getAvailableBiometrics() async{

    List<BiometricType> availableBiometric;

    try{

      availableBiometric = await auth.getAvailableBiometrics();
    } on PlatformException catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }
    if(!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _availableBiometrics = availableBiometric;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate() async {
    bool authenticated = false;

    try{
      authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
          localizedReason: "Scan your finger to authentie",
          useErrorDialogs: true,
          stickAuth: false
      );
    }on PlatformException catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }

    if(!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      //here we can add what our app will do if the user authenticated first
      autherized = authenticated ? "Autherized success" : "Failed to authenticate";
      if(authenticated) {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
      }
      print(autherized);
      // note that you must configure your device  and add a finger print
    });
  }
  //before we test our app we should first initate the state and call
  // our tow first function

  @override
  void initState() {
    //TOdo: implement initstate
    _checkBiometric();
    _getAvailableBiometrics();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xfFF3C3E52),
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 24.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Login,", style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 48.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.asset(
                          'assets/fingerprint.webp',
                          width: 120.0,
                        ),
                        Text("FingerPrint auth", style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),),
                        Container(
                          width: 150.0,
                          child: Text("Authenticate using your fingerprint instead of your password",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                height: 1.5
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: _authenticate,
                            elevation: 0.0,
                            color: Color(0xFfF04A5ED),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),

                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                              child: Text("Autentic", style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```